# Relationships question in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, playframework

I'm learning Hibernate and Play framework (also add Java into account...). I'm having problems saving this kind of entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User extends Model {



        @Required
    public String username;

        @Column(name="user_displayname",nullable=true)
    public String displayname;

        @Password
        public String user_password;

        @Email
        @Column(name="user_email",nullable=false,unique=true)
        public String user_email;

        public String user_salt;

        public Date user_joindate;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinTable(name="users_meta")
        public UserMeta userdata;

        @Required
        public boolean user_isActive;

        @OneToOne(targetEntity=UserPhotos.class,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinColumn(name="id",referencedColumnName="userID")
        public UserPhotos userPhoto;

        @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinTable(name="links_rol2user")
        public List<Rol> rol;
        public User (String username, models.Pass password, String user_email) {
            this.username = username;
            this.user_password = password.getHashedPassword();
            this.user_salt = password.getUserHash();
            this.user_email = user_email;
            this.user_joindate = new Date();
            this.user_isActive = false;

        }
```

This is my code when I'm registering a user

```
        // check if the validation has errors
        if(validation.hasErrors()) {
          params.flash(); // add http parameters to the flash scope
          validation.keep(); // keep the errors for the next request
          register();
        } else {
                Cache.delete(uuid);
                Pass pass = new Pass(password,new Date().toString());
                User newUser = new User(firstName, pass, email);
                UserMeta utest = new UserMeta(newUser.id);
                utest.setUserTownID(pueblos);
                newUser.setUserMeta(utest);
                newUser.save();
                Logger.info("NewUser ID : %s", newUser.getId());
//                UserMeta userInfo = new UserMeta(newUser.getId());
//                userInfo.setUserTownID(pueblos);
//                userInfo.save();

                // TODO salvar foto a null

                // Confirmation left
                Cache.set("thankyou", "alright!", "3mn");
                thankyou();
        }
```

I'm trying to save the userMeta, it does creates a new record when I set the userMeta object into newUser (not visible right now), but it doesn't insert the new ID created in newUser.

What kind of relation do I need? before I tweaked the code as it is now, it was a OneToOne relationship, worked quite well, but now when I was completing the register functions it kinda hit me that I needed to save userMeta object too..

If you need more info let me know, I don't know if I explained it well or not, just trying to get the hang of how Hibernate do relations, etc.

Adding UserMeta:

*/

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users_meta")
public class UserMeta extends Model {

    @Lob
    @Column(name="userBio")
    public String userBio;
    @Column(name="userPhotoID",nullable=true)
    public Long userPhotoID = null;
    @Column(name="userRoleID", nullable=false)
    public Long userRoleID = 2L;


    @Lob
    public String userDescription;
    @Column(name="userViews", nullable=false)
    public Long userViews = 0L;
    @Column(name="userFavoriteCount", nullable=false)
    public Long userFavoriteCount = 0L;
    @Column(name="userTotalComments", nullable=false)
    public Long userTotalComments = 0L;
    @Column(name="userTotalUploadedVideos", nullable=false)
    public Long userTotalUploadedVideos = 0L;

    public Long userTownID;


    public Long userID;
    public UserMeta() {}
    public UserMeta(Long userid) {
        this.userBio = "El usuario no ha escrito nada todavia!";
        this.userDescription = "El usuario todavia no se ha describido!";
        this.userID = userid;

    }
    public Long getUserTownID() {
        return userTownID;
    }

    public void setUserTownID(Long userTownID) {
        this.userTownID = userTownID;
    }
}
```

// pass model

```
public class Pass {

    protected String hashed;
    protected String userHash;

    public Pass(String passwordToHash, String salt) {

        StringBuffer passSalt = new StringBuffer(passwordToHash);
        this.userHash = DigestUtils.md5Hex(salt);
        passSalt.append(this.userHash);
        passSalt.append(Play.configuration.getProperty("application.passwordSalt"));

        this.hashed = DigestUtils.sha512Hex(passSalt.toString());

    }
    public String getHashedPassword() {
        return this.hashed;
    }
    public String getUserHash() {

        return this.userHash;
    }
```

}

Comment: How does UserMeta and Pass class look like?

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a lot going on there! But from what I can tell, you problem is with the id that you are passing into the UserMeta.

As you are extending Model, the id is being generated by the Model class. However, this is not set until after the entity is saved to the database (as the id is auto-generated by the database).

Therefore, because you are passing the id into the UserMeta before the User object is saved, the value of id will be null.

If you can save the User object before you create your UserMeta object, your code should work.

Comment: I used to do that :), but then the getUserMeta (userData variable) persistence will continue. For example, I save the User object, an exception occurs and it says something about userData (variable with the joins, etc), that it either has to be Transient or something else because as far as it goes, when I save the user object, its expecting the variable to have some kind of data to save too. :( ... well, since I got my cool back (kinda went nuts after several tries) I'll try to figure out what to do, any suggestion is welcome with arms wide open :)

Comment: One option would be to extend GenericModel instead of Model, and create your own id, or link via the user_email as it is unique and you have the value up front. I would be interested to know what your error was when you saved your User object first. I am not sure why this would fail.

Comment: I'll take a loot at it, sorry for the late answer, been on a busy week. Thanks for the help!